# Why do we minimise the loss between the target Q values and 'local' Q values?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, deep-rl, double-dqn

I have a question regarding the loss function of target networks and current (online) networks. I understand the action value function. What I am unsure about is why we seek to minimise the loss between the `qVal` for the next state in our target network and the **current** state in the local network. The Nature paper by Mnih et al. is well explained, however, I am not getting from it the purpose of the above. Here is my training portion from a script I am running:

```
for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
    target_qVal = self.model.predict(state)

    # print(target_qVal)

    if done:
        target_qVal[0][action] = reward #done
    else:
        # predicted q value for next state from target model
        pred = self.target_model.predict(next_state)[0]
        target_qVal[0][action] = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(pred)

    # indentation position?
    self.model.fit(np.array(state), 
                   np.array(target_qVal), 
                   batch_size=batch_size,
                   verbose=0, 
                   shuffle=False, 
                   epochs=1)
```

I understand that the expected return is the immediate reward plus the cumulative sum of discounted rewards looking into the future $s'$ (correct me if I'm wrong in my understanding) when following a given policy.

My fundamental misunderstanding is the loss equation:

$$L = [r + \gamma \max Q(s',a'; \theta') - Q(s,a; \theta)],$$

where $\theta'$ and $\theta$ are the weights of the target and online neural networks, respectively.

*Why do we aim to minimize the Q value of the next state in the target model and the Q value of the current state in the online model?*

A bonus question would be, in order to collect $Q(s,a)$ values for dimensionality reduction (as in Mnih et al t-sne plot), would I simply collect the `target_qVal[0]` values during training and feed them into a list after each step to accumulate the Q values over time?

Comment: could you please edit your question so the loss function is written using LaTeX as at the moment it is unreadable.

Comment: I have edited your post to fix some formatting issues, etc. Please, make sure that it is still consistent with your original post.

Comment: thank you! apologies for not correctly entewring the equation initially. this is correct and does convey my question around why it is the Q of s' and a' minus q val of current s and a.

Answer (score 1):

The loss function is designed in a way to approximate the bellman optimality for $Q^*(s,a)$. Given an optimal policy $\pi^*$, $Q^*(s,a)$ satisfies the equation $$Q^*(s,a) = r(s) + \gamma max_{a'}\sum_{s'}P(s'|s,a)Q^*(s',a')$$

At convergence, the highest $Q$ value that I can get taking action $a$ in state $s$ is equal to the reward I get for taking action $a$ and the max $Q$ values at the next state.

You can see in the loss function that the DQN tries to attain a $Q^*(s,a)$ value that closely approximates the equation above.

On a side note, in model based RL setting, the bellman optimality for $Q^*$ is expressed as $$Q^*(s,a) = r(s) + \gamma \sum_{s'}P(s'|s,a)V^*(s)$$ $V^*(s')$ is used in the model based case because $V^*(s)$ by definition represents the highest possible value attainable at state $s'$ following $\pi^*$. In model free setting, $V^*$ is replaced by $Q^*$ because computing $V^*$ is not useful in achieving model free control without a transition model $P(s'|s,a)$

Comment: OP is asking about use of target network for setting TD target (as opposed to the "current" Q function approximation)